# Carousel slider not displaying full content

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using lightslider to add a carousel to my page. The problem I'm having is that it's cutting off the content at the bottom, worse so when I scale in the browser to view it at a mobile size. This is most noticeable on the 2nd slide for some reason

When i view the code via the inspect option on chrome a height value seems to be added the

An example of the carousel is here

http://www.gerrymckay.co.uk/slider

Javascript

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#content-slider").lightSlider({
            loop:true,
            keyPress:true
        });
        $('#image-gallery').lightSlider({
            gallery:true,
            item:1,
            thumbItem:9,
            slideMargin: 0,
            speed:5000,
            auto:true,
            loop:true,
            onSliderLoad: function() {
                $('#image-gallery').removeClass('cS-hidden');
            }  
        });
    });
  </script>

  (function ($, undefined) {
  'use strict';
  var defaults = {
    item: 1,
    autoWidth: false,
    slideMove: 1,
    slideMargin: 10,
    addClass: '',
    mode: 'slide',
    useCSS: true,
    cssEasing: 'ease', //'cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0.25, 1)',
    easing: 'linear', //'for jquery animation',//
    speed: 400, //ms'
    auto: true,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    loop: false,
    slideEndAnimation: true,
    pause: 10000,
    keyPress: false,
    controls: true,
    prevHtml: '',
    nextHtml: '',
    rtl: false,
    adaptiveHeight: false,
    vertical: false,
    verticalHeight: 500,
    vThumbWidth: 100,
    thumbItem: 10,
    pager: true,
    gallery: false,
    galleryMargin: 5,
    thumbMargin: 5,
    currentPagerPosition: 'middle',
    enableTouch: true,
    enableDrag: true,
    freeMove: true,
    swipeThreshold: 40,
    responsive: [],
    /* jshint ignore:start */
    onBeforeStart: function ($el) {},
    onSliderLoad: function ($el) {},
    onBeforeSlide: function ($el, scene) {},
    onAfterSlide: function ($el, scene) {},
    onBeforeNextSlide: function ($el, scene) {},
    onBeforePrevSlide: function ($el, scene) {}
    /* jshint ignore:end */
};
```

CSS

```
.test {text-align: center; display:flex-inline;
}

.test p {color: #ffffff; font-size: 14px;}

.testname {
color: #64D9E2;
font-size: 14px;
}

.content-slider li{
text-align: center;
color: #FFF;
width: 100%;
}

.lSSlideOuter {
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none
}
.lightSlider:before, .lightSlider:after {
content: " ";
display: table;
}
.lightSlider {
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
}
.lSSlideWrapper {
max-width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
.lSSlideWrapper > .lightSlider:after {
clear: both;
}
.lSSlideWrapper .lSSlide {
-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
-ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
transform: translate(0px, 0px);
-webkit-transition: all 1s;
-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform,height;
-moz-transition-property: -moz-transform,height;
transition-property: transform,height;
-webkit-transition-duration: inherit !important;
transition-duration: inherit !important;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: inherit !important;
transition-timing-function: inherit !important;
}
.lSSlideWrapper .lSFade {
position: relative;
}
.lSSlideWrapper .lSFade > * {
position: absolute !important;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 9;
margin-right: 0;
width: 100%;
}
.lSSlideWrapper.usingCss .lSFade > * {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
transition-delay: 0s;
-webkit-transition-duration: inherit !important;
transition-duration: inherit !important;
-webkit-transition-property: opacity;
transition-property: opacity;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: inherit !important;
transition-timing-function: inherit !important;
}
.lSSlideWrapper .lSFade > *.active {
z-index: 10;
}
.lSSlideWrapper.usingCss .lSFade > *.active {
opacity: 1;
}
/** /!!! End of core css Should not edit !!!/**/

/* Pager */
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSpg {
margin: 10px 0 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSpg > li {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
padding: 0 5px;
}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSpg > li a {
background-color: #222222;
border-radius: 30px;
display: inline-block;
height: 8px;
overflow: hidden;
text-indent: -999em;
width: 8px;
position: relative;
z-index: 99;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear 0s;
transition: all 0.5s linear 0s;
}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSpg > li:hover a, .lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSpg > 
li.active a {
background-color: #428bca;
}
.lSSlideOuter .media {
opacity: 0.8;
}
.lSSlideOuter .media.active {
opacity: 1;
}
/* End of pager */

/** Gallery */
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery {
list-style: none outside none;
padding-left: 0;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
-o-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
-moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery li {
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transition: border-radius 0.12s linear 0s 0.35s linear 0s;
transition: border-radius 0.12s linear 0s 0.35s linear 0s;
}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery li.active, .lSSlideOuter 
.lSPager.lSGallery li:hover {
border-radius: 5px;
}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery img {
display: block;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery:before, .lSSlideOuter 
.lSPager.lSGallery:after {
content: " ";
display: table;
}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery:after {
clear: both;
}
/* End of Gallery*/

/* slider actions */
.lSAction > a {
width: 32px;
display: block;
top: 50%;
height: 32px;
background-image: url('../img/controls.png');
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
z-index: 99;
margin-top: -16px;
opacity: 0.5;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s linear 0s;
transition: opacity 0.35s linear 0s;
}
.lSAction > a:hover {
opacity: 1;
}
.lSAction > .lSPrev {
background-position: 0 0;
left: 10px;
}
.lSAction > .lSNext {
background-position: -32px 0;
right: 10px;
}
.lSAction > a.disabled {
pointer-events: none;
}
.cS-hidden {
height: 1px;
opacity: 0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="testimonials" >

<div class="item">
        <h2 class="white">Testimonials</h2>

           <ul id="content-slider" class="content-slider">
            <li>
            <div class="test">
                <img src="images/pr.png">
                    <p span style="display: block;">Lorem ipsum dolor 
sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat 
mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, 
viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.

Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor 
mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</p>
                    <span class="testname">Full Name - Profession title 
goes here</span>
            </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="test">
                <img src="images/ib.png">
                    <p>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. 
Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed 
arcu. Cras consequat.

Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas 
auguae, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui 
mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.

Phasellus ultrices nulla quis nibh. Quisque a lectus. Donec 
consectetuer ligula vulputate sem tristique cursus. Nam nulla quam, 
gravida non, commodo a, sodales sit amet, nisi.</p>
                    <span class="testname">Full Name - Profession title 
goes here</span><br>
            </div>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: please create a minimum complete and verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If we answer your question you're going to change your website by applying the provided solution, which will make the question no longer relevant for future users. Pay it forward by allowing your question to remain helpful for future visitors with a similar problem. Add a runnable [mcve] in the question itself. Most veterans here dont even consider opening external links (on general principles) if you don't make the question self-sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your slider is taking the height of the content in your first slide. If you want it to expand when you go to taller slides, set its `adaptiveHeight` to true.

There is [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider/issues/271) about this less-than-desirable behavior.

Comment: Is there no way of working out which one is the biggest in height and then setting them all to that rather than slider height changing for each slide?

Comment: @Gezzamondo Not natively in the lightSlider options, but some people have found workarounds ([example](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider/issues/271#issuecomment-244922225))